# AVR Assembler Labels

Tags: assembly, avr

According to doc1022, p. 17 (AVR Assembler User Guide):

> User defined labels which are given the value of the location counter at the place they
>   appear.

My question is, what goes into the opcode when a label is used in a `jmp` and in an `rjmp` instruction since a label is really the value of the location counter at the place the label appears? Secondly, if there exists an official (or non official) document answering my question, do you know where can I find it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are you asking how `jmp` instructions are encoded or are you asking where the `jmp` instruction jumps to?

Comment: [1] In the "8-bit AVR Instruction Set" document, under RJMP, the performed operation is stated as: "PC ← PC + k + 1" and the syntax for this operation is stated as: "RJMP k". Now if we think labels as: <someLabel>==<someConstant>, RJMP should always fail because in that case, the absolute address to jump is being supplied into RJMP, instead of relative address. So I am asking: In rjmp operations where a label is used as the operand, I guess instead of supplying its real value, some relative value (something like "PC - someLabel") is done. If that's the case, where can I obtain the relevant

Comment: [2] official document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembler uses the correct encoding of a jump instruction that jumps to the label given as operand. That is after the instruction executes the value of PC will be equal to the address of the label. For the `RJMP` instruction this means that the assembler doesn't use the address of label directly in the encoded instruction, instead it encodes it as a constant operand `k`, where `k` solves the equation `label = PC + k + 1`.

I don't know if this is explicitly stated in any official document, but this how all assemblers work. Otherwise it's would pretty dumb.  In particular the following example given in section 4.3 of the [AVR Assembler Guide](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc1022.pdf) wouldn't actually be an infinite loop if the AVR assembler didn't work this way:

```
test: rjmp test ; Infinite loop (Instruction)
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually the reason for me asking this question is, I am aiming to use a label just as if it was "a pointer to the beginning of a Program Memory array". That is: I am trying to do:  If (someArgument - someConstant) == 0, go to someLabel.  If (someArgument - someConstant) == N, go to (someLabel + N*someProgramMemorySpaceConstant).  I could have done this via a specific pointer register but it is occupied with another task in my program. So if I can learn how rjmp works exactly, I can do that.

Comment: you can not use rjmp to load your data. Surely you can use the label as an index to the data but if you want du read the data you have to load the adress int one of the pointer regsiter sets.

Answer (score 0):

Labels appear in assembly code, but the assembly code must be turned into machine instructions to be run on the device.

What this quote is saying is that as the assembly file is processed, the label in `jmp` instructions is replaced with the address of the instruction following the label. The address itself is discovered during the compilation process as the instructions are collated.

If you want to look at actual machine code that is produced, you can view the intel `.hex` file produced by avr-gcc. There is a [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) to help you interpret the intel hex file format.

Edit in response to OP's comment:

For `rjmp`, the number supplied is calculated by the compiler by taking the address of the instruction following the label and subtracting the address of the `rjmp` instruction. Note that `rjmp` only works if the jump is small enough, while `jmp` can go to any address.

If you want an actual document describing that process, you need to research the compiler you are using. There may not be such a document explaining exactly what you want, but the source code is available for avr-gcc.

Note that most assembly code is actually produced by compilers themselves when processing high-level language code such as C. The choice of `jmp` versus `rjmp` and how to calculate the number to give to the instruction can even depend on compiler switches. Compiling with `-O3` or `-Os` will give different resulting assembly code.

Comment: Thanks. Actually what I want to learn is what exactly happens when a label is supplied to an rjmp instruction. (please see my comments under the initial post in this thread)

Comment: [1] Thanks but what I wonder is, for example if I write "rjmp 5", that's a valid instruction and that will make "PC <- PC + 5 + 1", according to the reference manual. Now if one thinks that a label is really some constant (that is equal to the value of the location counter at the place the label appears), then when I write "rjmp someLabel" and if it gets interpreted as "rjmp someLabelsValue", then I should get a wrong execution since someLabelsValue is the absolute address of the place that I want to jump, instead of the relative one. So this suggests that, when interpreting rjmp instructions

Comment: [2] using labels, the assembler should regard the instruction "rjmp someLabel" not as "rjmp someLabelsValue" but as "rjmp <someLabelsValue - theValueInPC - 1>". Finally, my question is, where is the information that an rjmp instruction using a label is interpreted like that?

Comment: And I am using an assembler right now actually, so the question is not about a compiler but about the assembler.